# How to Make hyperlink to sub domain in TypeScript Execute File

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, routes, hyperlink

I am trying to input a link pointing to a subdomain into the navigation menu of a react theme. I am a bit embarrassed to ask the community for something that is most likely very simple. However, I've had a hard time finding any relatable examples on the web to help guide me. Below is the code and how I thought it would work, however it doesn't since it uses the current path ahead of the hyperlink.

```
#RouteName.ts
export enum RouteName {
  Home      = "/"
  About     = "/About"
  Service   = "/Service"
  Portfolio = "https://sub.domain.com/"
  Contact   = "/Contact"
}

#Navigation.tsx
const ROUTES = [
  {url: RouteName.Home,      name: "Home"},
  {url: RouteName.About,     name: "About"},
  {url: RouteName.Service,   name: "Service"},
  {url: RouteName.Portfolio, name: "Portfolio"},
  {url: RouteName.Contact,   name: "Contact"},
];

<Menu className="Menu">
  {ROUTES.map((item) => (
    <li key={item.url} className={pathname === item.url ? "active" : ""}>
      <Link to={item.url}>{item.name}</Link>
    </li>
  ))}
</Menu>

#App.TSX
<Routes>                      
  <Route path={RouteName.Portfolio} element = {
    <>
      <TopNav />
      <Portfolio />                                              
    </>
  }/>
  .....etc
</Routes>
```

Result: localhost:3000/page-currently-on/https://sub.domain.com/

Need: https://sub.domain.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Link` is a component from react Router and is meant for links inside your website. For external links, you can use a simple `<a/>` tag

`<a href="https://sub.domain.com/">Portfolio</a>`

---

It would probably be better to create a route on `/Portfolio` with a redirect like so:

```
<Route path='/Portfolio' component={() => { 
     window.location.href = 'https://sub.domain.com/'; 
     return null;
}}/>
```

Then, you don't have to worry about it.

```
export enum RouteName {
  Home      = "/"
  About     = "/About"
  Service   = "/Service"
  Portfolio = "/Portfolio"
  Contact   = "/Contact"
}
```

This solution creates makes the website easily expandable.

Comment: Routes are setup in the theme likeso, I could not figure out how to include the redirect.                     <Routes>                      
                      <Route path={RouteName.home} element = {
                        <>
                          <TopNav />
                          <Marketplace />                                              
                        </>
                      }/>

Comment: Have you tried using the `a` tag instead then ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `pathname` when you want to link to the exact URL. In your case

```js
<Link to={{pathname: item.url}} />
```

I know this doesn't play well with your types so have to trial and error a bit to implement it cleanly.

Source: https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/07/how-to-add-an-external-link-with-react-router/